# Problems when viewing a pdf-file in browsers. Pieces of letters have disappeared

Tags: pdf

I have strange problems when viewing a pdf-file in browsers: chrome, yandex, edge. In FireFox pdf is viewing correctly.
OS Windows 10.
Picture is attached.

[image]

[image]
normal view

Comment: (1) Ideally, you should include the Image where it is working too, so that we can compare & check what is missing & what may be going wrong ! (2) In case the Document is "free" , you should include the Document itself , so what we can figure out what is wrong with it or what is wrong with the Web Browsers ! (3) It may be some missing "font" or "localization" Issues !

Comment: Most likely the problem is with the browser. The file is displayed correctly on other computers. Unfortunately, I can't upload the file itself, because it contains personal data. The publication of such files is punishable by law.

Comment: What is the graphics processor, and driver, you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running into this (new) known Chromium, Window 10, Intel UHD graphics driver issue.

https://support.papersapp.com/support/solutions/articles/30000046026-pdf-rendering-issues-in-google-chrome-on-windows-10

Comment: Ryan, Thank you very much! I'll try this recommendations.